Command to handle a Dynamics 365 Security Role
Is there an available powershell command for handling security roles?
Here is a sample security roles:
Security Role: Sample Standard User
Entity: Contact
Privilege: Read, Append, and Append To

Security Role: Sample Advance User
Entity: Contact
Privilege: Create, Read, Write, Append, and Append to

Security Role: Sample Admin User
Entity: Contact
Privilege: Create, Read, Write, Delete, Append, and Append to

Configuration for security roles in microsoft dynamics is tedious right?
Using this example, the goal is to replicate a specific security role then apply additional privileges.
Now using the example given above, if we can replicate "Sample Standard User" using powershell to create "Sample Advance User" then add "Create and Read" privilege (again using powershell), we can skip the tedious part of the configuration and create a them programmatically instead.

Do these commands do anything?

If i have understood correctly, you can utilize the following code piece that i used for dynamics roles creation assignment and expiration.
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser

Import-Module Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell

$connection = Get-CrmConnection -InteractiveMode

Retrieve the Original Security Role:
$originalRole = Get-CrmSecurityRole -conn $connection -RoleName "Sample Standard User"

Clone the Security Role:
$newRole = New-CrmSecurityRole -conn $connection -OriginalRole $originalRole -NewRoleName "Sample Advance User"

Add Privileges to the New Role:
$entityName = "contact"
$privileges = @("Create", "Write")

foreach ($privilege in $privileges) {
    Set-CrmSecurityRolePrivilege -conn $connection -RoleId $newRole.RoleId -EntityName $entityName -PrivilegeName $privilege -AccessLevel "Organization"
}

to Verify the Changes:
$updatedRole = Get-CrmSecurityRole -conn $connection -RoleName "Sample Advance User"


Can you tell me the Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell version? Because in version 2.8.19, I cannot use commands "Get-CrmSecurityRole" and "Set-CrmSecurityRolePrivilege", these are undefined.

This answer is based on the answer posted by @Laviza Falak Naz.
The code mainly includes the following steps:

Create a connection

Retrieve the necessary information for the StandardRole (if the StandardRole also needs to be created, call method Create-Role and Add-Privilege)

Create a new role.

Copy the privileges from the StandardRole to the new role

Add more privileges to the new role
# Install the Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell module if not installed yet
if (-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell)) {
    Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser
}

# Import the module
Import-Module Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell

# Define privilegeDepthMask enum
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
public enum PrivilegeDepthMask
{
    Basic = 1,
    Local = 2,
    Deep = 4,
    Global = 8
}
"@

# Define privilegeDepth enum
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
public enum PrivilegeDepth
{
    Basic = 0,
    Local = 1,
    Deep = 2,
    Global = 3
}
"@

# Define AccessRight enum
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
public enum AccessRight
{
    None = 0,
    ReadAccess = 1,
    WriteAccess = 2,
    AppendAccess = 4,
    AppendToAccess = 16,
    CreateAccess = 32,
    DeleteAccess = 65536,
    ShareAccess = 262144,
    AssignAccess = 524288
}
"@

# Mapping dictionary for PrivilegeType to AccessRight
$privilegeTypeToAccessRightMap = @{
    "Read"     = [AccessRight]::ReadAccess
    "Write"    = [AccessRight]::WriteAccess
    "Append"   = [AccessRight]::AppendAccess
    "AppendTo" = [AccessRight]::AppendToAccess
    "Create"   = [AccessRight]::CreateAccess
    "Delete"   = [AccessRight]::DeleteAccess
    "Share"    = [AccessRight]::ShareAccess
    "Assign"   = [AccessRight]::AssignAccess
}

# Function to get role by name
function Get-RoleByName {
    param (
        [string]$roleName,
        [Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient]$conn
    )
    $fetchXML = @"
<fetch mapping='logical'>
    <entity name='role'>
        <attribute name='roleid' />
        <attribute name='name' />
        <attribute name='businessunitid' />
        <filter type='and'>
            <condition attribute='name' operator='eq' value='$roleName' />
            <condition attribute='parentroleid' operator='null' />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
"@
    return Get-CrmRecordsByFetch -conn $conn -Fetch $fetchXML
}

# Function to map PrivilegeDepthMask to PrivilegeDepth
function Get-PrivilegeDepth {
    param (
        [PrivilegeDepthMask]$privilegeDepthMask,
        [string]$ownershipType
    )

    Write-Host "PrivilegeDepthMask value: $privilegeDepthMask"

    if ($ownershipType -eq "OrganizationOwned") {
        return [PrivilegeDepth]::Global
    }

    if ($privilegeDepthMask -eq [PrivilegeDepthMask]::Basic) {
        return [PrivilegeDepth]::Basic
    }
    elseif ($privilegeDepthMask -eq [PrivilegeDepthMask]::Local) {
        return [PrivilegeDepth]::Local
    }
    elseif ($privilegeDepthMask -eq [PrivilegeDepthMask]::Deep) {
        return [PrivilegeDepth]::Deep
    }
    elseif ($privilegeDepthMask -eq [PrivilegeDepthMask]::Global) {
        return [PrivilegeDepth]::Global
    }
    else {
        throw "Invalid PrivilegeDepthMask value: $privilegeDepthMask"
    }
}

# Function to create a role if it does not exist
function Create-Role {
    param (
        [string]$roleName,
        [Guid]$businessUnitId,
        [Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient]$conn
    )

    $role = Get-RoleByName -roleName $roleName -conn $conn

    if ($role.CrmRecords.Count -eq 0) {
        # Create the new role
        $newRole = New-CrmRecord -EntityLogicalName role -Fields @{
            name           = $roleName
            businessunitid = New-Object Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference("businessunit", $businessUnitId)
        } -conn $conn

        Write-Host "New role '$roleName' created successfully."
        return $newRole
    }
    else {
        # Use the existing role
        $roleId = $role.CrmRecords[0].roleid
        Write-Host "Role '$roleName' already exists. Using the existing role."
        return $roleId
    }
}

# Function to add a single privilege to a role
function Add-Privilege {
    param (
        [Guid]$roleId,
        [Guid]$privilegeId,
        [int]$depth,
        [Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient]$conn
    )

    # Create the RolePrivilege object
    $rolePriv = New-Object Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.RolePrivilege
    $rolePriv.PrivilegeId = $privilegeId
    $rolePriv.Depth = $depth

    # Create the AddPrivilegesRoleRequest object
    $addPrivRoleReq = New-Object Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.AddPrivilegesRoleRequest
    $addPrivRoleReq.RoleId = $roleId
    $addPrivRoleReq.Privileges = @($rolePriv)

    # Execute the request
    $response = $conn.ExecuteCrmOrganizationRequest($addPrivRoleReq)

    Write-Host "Privilege with ID $privilegeId added to role successfully."
}

# Function to get privilege ID by entity metadata and access right
function Get-PrivilegeId {
    param (
        [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.EntityMetadata]$entityMetadata,
        [AccessRight]$accessRight
    )

    foreach ($privilege in $entityMetadata.Privileges) {
        # Map PrivilegeType to AccessRight
        if ($privilegeTypeToAccessRightMap.ContainsKey($privilege.PrivilegeType.ToString()) -and $privilegeTypeToAccessRightMap[$privilege.PrivilegeType.ToString()] -eq $accessRight) {
            return $privilege.PrivilegeId
        }
    }

    throw "Privilege with AccessRight $accessRight not found."
}

# Function to copy privileges from one role to another
function Copy-Privileges {
    param (
        [Guid]$sourceRoleId,
        [Guid]$targetRoleId,
        [Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient]$conn,
        [string]$ownershipType
    )

    # Retrieve all privileges associated with the source role
    $rolePrivileges = Get-CrmRecords -conn $conn -EntityLogicalName roleprivileges -FilterAttribute roleid -FilterOperator eq -FilterValue $sourceRoleId -Fields privilegeid, privilegedepthmask

    foreach ($privilege in $rolePrivileges.CrmRecords) {
        # Log the privilege object to understand its structure
        #Write-Host "Privilege object: $($privilege | Out-String)"

        # Extract the integer value from the privilegedepthmask property
        $privilegeDepthMaskValue = [int]$privilege.privilegedepthmask
        Write-Host "Extracted PrivilegeDepthMask value: $privilegeDepthMaskValue"

        # Cast the extracted integer value to the PrivilegeDepthMask enum type
        $privilegeDepthMask = [PrivilegeDepthMask]$privilegeDepthMaskValue
        Write-Host "Casted PrivilegeDepthMask enum: $privilegeDepthMask"
        $depth = Get-PrivilegeDepth -privilegeDepthMask $privilegeDepthMask -ownershipType $ownershipType

        # Add the privilege to the target role
        Add-Privilege -roleId $targetRoleId -privilegeId ([Guid]::Parse($privilege.privilegeid)) -depth $depth -conn $conn
    }
}

# Change below values to match your needs
$username = "admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "yourpassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)
$standardRoleName = "Sample Standard User"
$newRoleName = "Sample Advance User"
$entityName = "contact"
$addPrivilege = [AccessRight]::AppendAccess
$addPrivilegeDepth = [PrivilegeDepth]::Local
$serverUrl = "https://domain.crmX.dynamics.com/"
$organizationName = "Demo"
$conn = Get-CrmConnection -serverUrl $serverUrl -credential $credential -organizationName $organizationName

# Check if the connection was successful
if ($conn -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Failed to connect to CRM. Exiting script."
    exit
}

# Retrieve the standard role
$standardRole = Get-RoleByName -roleName $standardRoleName -conn $conn

# Check if the role was found
if ($standardRole.CrmRecords.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "$standardRoleName role not found."
    exit
}

# Retrieve the business unit ID from the standard role
$businessUnitId = $standardRole.CrmRecords[0].businessunitid_Property.Value.Id

# Create the new role if it does not exist
$newRoleId = Create-Role -roleName $newRoleName -businessUnitId $businessUnitId -conn $conn

# Retrieve the entity metadata to check the owningtype
$entityMetadata = Get-CrmEntityMetadata -conn $conn -EntityLogicalName $entityName -EntityFilters "all"

# Copy privileges from the standard role to the new role
Copy-Privileges -sourceRoleId $standardRole.CrmRecords[0].roleid -targetRoleId $newRoleId -conn $conn -ownershipType $entityMetadata.OwnershipType

# Add the specified privilege to the new role
$privilegeId = Get-PrivilegeId -entityMetadata $entityMetadata -accessRight $addPrivilege
Add-Privilege -roleId $newRoleId -privilegeId $privilegeId -depth $addPrivilegeDepth -conn $conn



The business unit used in the code is the root business unit(Get-RoleByName) for best practice.
For organization owned entity, privilege depth only has "Basic" and "Global"
